# Video capture with EasyCap shows double height in VLC

Tags: video, vlc, easycap

After switching from Linux Mint Cinnamon to Ubuntu I have a problem with my EasyCap USBTV007, which I have succesfully used for transferring a bunch of old VHS tapes.

The method I used was to stream it in VLC like this:

Media -> Open Capture Device

- Capture mode: Video camera
- Video device name: /dev/video1
- Audio device name: hw:1,0
- Video standard: 625 lines/50 Hz

The problem is that the picture now appears to be stretched to double height. It's still shown as 4:3 though, so it's only half of it that's visible.

I have of course tried to play around with various settings, as well as reinstalling Mint. But that just lead to a new problem, namely that the picture is very dark.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be a definite or really helpful answer, but I can’t comment due to a lack of reputation on this site.

The behaviour you get is probably a bug in the current version of the VLC player. I get exactly the same with two different webcams built into laptops from two different vendors. Only the upper half of the video is displayed stretched like you described.

You should be able to view an undistorted video if you use mpv or ffplay to display your video source.

```
mpv /dev/video1
# Or
ffplay /dev/video1
```

If this works, you can use ffmpeg to capture your tapes. This is a very basic command that captures only the video and stores it as a *lossless* H264 stream. Adjust the parameters to your needs. (Beware: If you use the settings below, the video gets *huge*!)

```
ffmpeg -i /dev/video1 -c:v libx264 -crf 0 out.mkv
```